# Enqueue ONLY Plugin Styles and Scripts

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Is there a way to enqueue only plugin styles and scripts without wp_head?  I have a plugin I'm working on which overrides the page template, but I still want to include all other plugins without including the theme style.  Since theme developers don't always enqueue their styles and often hardcode the link, what's the best way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since theme developers don't always enqueue their styles and often hardcode the link, what's the best way around this?

There is *no* way *around* this. Simply said: Let them burn. They're doing it wrong and as a 3rd party code developer you don't have to take wannabe developers into account.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a similar issue this wont help if people have been arseholes and manually added script and style links but will hopefully help with those that are.

[Styles and Scripts, Selectively enqueue across entire site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235638/styles-and-scripts-selectively-enqueue-across-entire-site)