# Styles and Scripts, Selectively enqueue across entire site

Tags: plugins, scripts, css

Right I have a plugin I am making for a customer, this plugin is actually to display things on a window TV display they have which will connect to a webpage not linked publicly on the website.

I am looking to enqueue only the styles and scripts which that plugin has, and this is a major problem it seems because I know how to selectively check "is page" and then only do it for certain pages but this site has a lot ... and I mean A LOT of plugins which all enqueue styles & scripts as well as the template.

I can't be going into every plugin some custom some public to add conditional statements to each enqueue to check if the page is not the TV display.

So how could I get around this issue? There does not seem to be a hook or filter that would help me here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Right I figured this out myself not sure how "hacky" this is but basically this is the code:

```
public function filter_scripts_styles(){
    if(is_page($this->plugin_name)){
        //Same name is used for the style as the js file so can reuse this array
        $allowed = array('jquery', $this->plugin_name.'_scrollpath', $this->plugin_name);
        //Check Scripts First
        global $wp_scripts;
        foreach($wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
            if(!in_array($handle, $allowed)){
                //echo 'Dequeuing : '. $handle;
                wp_dequeue_script($handle);
            }
        }
        //Check styles
        global $wp_styles;
        foreach($wp_styles->queue as $handle ) {
            if(!in_array($handle, $allowed)){
                //echo 'Dequeuing : '. $handle;
                wp_dequeue_style($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I added an action to:

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_print_styles', $plugin_public, 'filter_scripts_styles' );
```

Which if your using normal WP would be;

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'filter_scripts_styles');
```

I added the names of the handles of the things I knew were needed on that page dequeued everything else.

Hopefully someone else will find this useful.